# Thin-border on WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'd like to create a window, using WPF, that has a thin border all the way around the form - i.e. no space for the title bar with the icon/caption and min/max/close buttons. For example, the "extra" icons form of the new Windows 7 taskbar:

[Example Image http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/6196/border.png](http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/6196/border.png)

I understand this can be done by setting the `WindowStyle = None` property, however, I am also using the [`DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969512(v=VS.85).aspx) API, which requires that the `Background` property be transparent. If I do this neither the window nor border are drawn, and only non-transparent controls on the form are drawn.

How can I achieve the thin border, whilst maintaining an Aero Glass effect on the main body of the form?

Answer (score 2):

Use `WindowStyle="None"` on the Window. [See MSDN for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="100" WindowStyle="None">
     Hello World
</Window>
```

Comment: you could also add a <Border> element setting the Thickness you need

Comment: I am using the `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` API to have an Aero Glass background on the whole form - setting `WindowStyle="None"` means only non-transparent parts of the form are drawn (and no border).

Comment: `WindowStyle="None"` will draw a border around the window exactly like in your screenshot.

Comment: I only get that border when I don't set the Background colour to "Transparent" (which, as far as I can tell, is required for `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` to work). If the Background colour is set to Transparent (Opacity is still 1.0) then no border is drawn.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is set `ResizeMode=CanResize` and then do the following in the code behind:

```
protected override IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr LParam, ref bool handled)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_NCHITTEST:
                    //if the mouse pointer is not over the client area of the tab
                    //ignore it - this disables resize on the glass chrome
                    //a value of 1 is the HTCLIENT enum value for the Client Area
                    if (DefWindowProc(hwnd, WM_NCHITTEST, wParam, LParam).ToInt32() == 1)
                    {
                        handled = true;
                    }
                    break;
     }
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, IntPtr wParam,
           IntPtr lParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the [Microsoft WPF Shell Integration Library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell)